# Using tensorflow on python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow on python3.9 but it is only available upto 3.8 .Is there any way in which i can use tensorflow without having to degrade to python3.8

I tried using venv but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There is no way without having to install python 3.8 in someway, tensor flow is just not built for python 3.9 yet.
You can check the versions of python tensorflow supports here https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#description